# Equivalent of rowlock in Cosmos DB collection query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following requirement:
Two instances of applications process the Cosmos DB collection documents by retrieving the document with property "status"="non processed".

Here are the steps:
- Read the documents that have property "status"="not processed"
- Mark the documents retrieved with "status"="inprogress" so that same set of documents is not retrieved by another application
- Process the documents in the application and update the status of the document to "processed"

In SQL world, we can accomplish this by applying rowlock on the selected rows and update the status column to a value which will not be picked up by another application. How can we accomplish this in Cosmos DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, this kind of functionality is not available in Azure Cosmos DB. Both applications will be able to read the document.

However what you can do is prevent an application to overwrite changes done by other application. This is accomplished by using [`Optimistic Concurrency Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control) in Cosmos DB.